# Itcl/Tcom/Tcl/Threads: Is this thread continuously running

Tags: pthreads, tcl, itcl

In of the places I have written itcl code in a thread that kills excel

```
method Kill_XL {} {
    thread::create {
        set rc [catch {exec taskkill /t /f /im Excel*} output]
    }
    sleep 5
}
```

After that, for several different wish shells the following command invokes Excel App but I can see it immediately exiting in task manager

```
(shh..) 2 % ::tcom::ref createobject Excel.Application
::tcom::handle0x027CE918
(shh..) 3 % ::tcom::ref createobject Excel.Application
::tcom::handle0x027CE918
```

The above is repeated for a several wish shells (each invoked after closing the previous wish shell).

On running any command, the error appears as:

```
"invalid command name ::tcom::handle0x027CE918"
```

But the following code works and opens up a Word application without a problem

```
(shh..) 4 % ::tcom::ref createobject Word.Application
::tcom::handle0x027CE918
```

After waiting for a long time (15-20 minutes), I restarted the wish shell and was able to run (without problem) the following code:

```
(shh..) 8 % set x [::tcom::ref createobject Excel.Application]
::tcom::handle0x0272EB58
(shh..) 9 % $x Visible 1
```

And a different error message this time after killing excel

```
(shh..) 10 % thread::create {
                set rc [catch {exec taskkill /t /f /im Excel*} output]
            }
tid00004658


(shh..) 11 % $x Visible 0
0x800706ba {The RPC server is unavailable.}
```

And then is starts all over again:

```
(shh..) 20 %  ::tcom::ref createobject Excel.Application
::tcom::handle0x0272EB58
(shh..) 21 % 
(shh..) 21 % ::tcom::handle0x0272EB58 Visible 1
invalid command name "::tcom::handle0x0272EB58"
```

Is the threaded kill causing problems - I am always sleeping 5 seconds to ensure the kill is successful.

Or is it some other (known) issue with tcom-Excel?

Also, giving the same app handles all the time

```
(shh..) 30 % foreach x  {. .} {puts [::tcom::ref createobject Excel.Application]}
::tcom::handle0x0272EB58
::tcom::handle0x0272EB58
```

Could this be a cleanup issue with unreleased tcom objects - does it not clenaup automatically on killing the excel process associated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was some problem with the OS - doesn't get repeated after OS was re-imaged.